# How to Accept / Decline appointments by using Zimbra Soap API

Tags: soap, zimbra

I have been worked out Creating Appointments from my Application to Zimbra by using Zimbra SOAP API.

Then i want's to **Accept / Decline / Tentative** zimbra appointments from my application itself. So that should get update in Zimbra calander.

Here i tried **SendInviteReplyRequest** Command from Zimbramail Services to send the Appointment accepted invitation.

**My Code :**

```
<SendInviteReplyRequest id="{mail-item-id}"
```

I have found that we have to give

```
id={mail-item-id}
```

as an attributes of  **SendInviteReplyRequest** command. But i don't know where should i get this **id={mail-item-id}** from Zimbra ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, I am in the same page as you but a little late , I have established connection with zimbra but I cant display appointments with java can you show me how please ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Accept, Decline and Tentative of the appointment.  First, We have to get the **{mail-item-id}** to pass as id into **SendInviteReplyRequest**.

The below code will help us to get the **{mail-item-id}** which is **invitation id** of the appointment. So we have to pass our Zimbra Appointment Id as a **uid** into **GetAppointmentRequest**.

```
<GetAppointmentRequest xmlns="urn:zimbraMail">
   <uid>Your Zimbra Unique Id</uid>
</GetAppointmentRequest>
```

Above said function will give the response  below

```
<GetAppointmentResponse xmlns="urn:zimbraMail">
  <appt uid="4cp5d81f-85e4-4949-a3ca-3a7d502cte8f" rev="96915">
    <inv compNum="0" id="1" type="appt" seq="7"></inv>
  </appt>
</GetAppointmentResponse>
```

from the response once xml result parse into array then ['APPT']['INV']['ID'] value have to set into id of the  SendInviteReplyRequest.

$mail-item-id = ['APPT']['INV']['ID'];

```
<SendInviteReplyRequest id="'.$mail-item-id.'">
```